# New entries on the GRUB

Tags: ubuntu, grub

I updated my Ubuntu, and after that there were two new lines on my GRUB screen.

```
Ubuntu 9.04, kernel 2.6.28-16-generic
Ubuntu 9.04, kernel 2.6.28-16-generic (recovery mode)
Ubuntu 9.04, kernel 2.6.28-11-generic
Ubuntu 9.04, kernel 2.6.28-11-generic (recovey mode)
Ubuntu 9.04, memtest86+
Other operating systems:
Microsoft Windows XP Home Edition
```

Do I have two kernels installed?
Do the old entries are still useful?
Each kernel takes up space? 
:P

And that's not all, when a get into the old version of Ubuntu, the wireless card stops working on any Ubuntu version until I get into Windows and then go back to Ubuntu.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Yes, you have two kernels installed.
- The older kernel is certainly useful if the new one doesn't boot.
- Yes, both kernels will occupy disk space(?!?)

It sounds like the older kernel is lacking some useful hardware support, so in that instance it should be fine to remove the older kernel using your package management tool of choice.

Comment: Thnak you, that's what I'm goint to do.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have two kernels.  It is possible they are on different drives (like an old drive image you plugged in via USB).  See /boot/grub/grub.cfg to be sure.